# RESTful design - how to model entity's attachments

Tags: rest, binary, attachment, binaryfiles

I am trying to model entity's attachments in REST. Let's say a defect entity can have multiple attachments attached to it. Every attachment has a description and some other properties (last modified, file size...) . The attachment itself is a file in any format (jpeg, doc ...)

I was wondering how should I model it RESTfully

I thought about the following two options:

#### First approach (using same resource, different representations):

- GET , content-type:XML on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will return the defect's 
  attachments metadata in XML format (description, last modified, file size...)
- GET , content-type:gzip on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will return the defect's attachments in a zip file
- GET , content-type:mime multi-part on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will return the defect's attachments in a multi-part message (binary data and XML metadata altogether)
- POST, content-type:XML on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will create new attachment, metadata only no file attached (then the user has to send PUT request with the binary data)
- POST , content-type:mime\multi-part on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will create the attachment, the client can send both metadata and file itself in a single roundtrip

#### Second approach (separate the attachment's data from the metadata):

- GET , content-type:XML on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will return the defect's 
  attachments metadata in XML format (description, last modified, file size...)
- GET , content-type:gzip on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments/files** will return the defect's attachments binary data in a single zip

Creating a new attachment, first call:

- POST, content-type:XML on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments** will create new attachment, metadata only no file attached (then the user has to send PUT request with the binary data)

Then add the binary data itself:

- POST , content-type:mime\multi-part on **http://my-app/defects/{id}/attachments/{id}/file** will create the attachment file

---

On one hand the first approach is more robust and efficient since the client can create\get the attachments metadata and binary data in single round trip. On the other hand, I am a bit reluctant to use the mime-multipart representation as it's more cumbersome to consume and produce.

**EDIT:** I checked out [flicker upload REST API](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.example.html). It seems they are using multi part messages to include both the photo and the photo attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't manage metadata separately.  A two-part action defeats the point of REST.

One smooth GET/POST/PUT/DELETE with one -- relatively -- complex payload is what's typically done.

The fact that it's multiple underlying "objects" in "tables" is irrelevant to REST.

At the REST level, it's just one complex object's state transmitted with one message.

Comment: thanks for your answer, would you suggest to try generate this "complex structure" in XML or mime multi part? passing binary in XMLs is not very efficient, but mime multipart is not an intuitive format.

Comment: JSON and YAML are more efficient than XML for this.

Answer (score 3):

Much of this problem has already been solved by the Atom Pub spec.  See [here](http://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023.html#media-link-entries)

One thing to be careful about in your proposed solutions is that you are using content negotiation to deliver different content.  I believe that is considered bad.  Content negotiation should only deliver different representations of the same content.

Comment: interesting reference, thanks. this approach requires two round-trips to create a new attachment. I need to decide how important is the single round trip requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure it does.  The example talks about PUTing the image as second step to simply update the image.  The original POST contained the image in the body.

Comment: you are right, sorry. the first step POSTs the image as binary data, so this message can't include additional properties of the image (e.g. description).